# Create right click menu pyQT Maya

Tags: python, pyqt, maya, pyside2

I am currently learning/Converting my `Maya.cmds` GUI over to PYQT. I have run into some problems learning how to create "popup menus"

Maya pop up menu example on `QPushButton`

[image]

This use to be second nature to me in `Maya.cmds` but since moving to Qt I am having problems finding any information about this. I would like to add Check boxes, Radial selections and `QLineEdit` inside this "popup menu".

Comment: first five links here: https://www.google.com/search?q=pyqt+maya e.g. http://danostrov.com/2012/10/27/creating-a-simple-ui-in-maya-using-pyqt/,

Comment: I'm a bit late to this, but right click menus are not specific to Maya. Search how to do a Qt context menu

Comment: Thanks I have found how to do it and will be posting a answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version I have put together, we are using a custom context menu to show our Qmenu with all our menu items.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")

    #   C R E A T E   L A Y O U T
        mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    #   C R E A T E   B U T T O N
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Right Click Me!')
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.btn)

    #   C O N N E C T   P O P U P   M E N U   T O   O U R   B U T T O N
        self.btn.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.btn.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showPopup)

    #   M E N U   I T E M S
        self.popupMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        self.PBSaveFileCB = self.popupMenu.addAction("Click")


    #   S H O W   P O P U P   M E N U
    def showPopup(self,position):
         self.popupMenu.exec_(self.btn.mapToGlobal(position))

def showUI():
    ui = MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    return ui

ui = showUI()
```